# iOS connecting to AppleScript code

Tags: ios, applescript, spotify

I have an appleScript code that controls the play/pause of Spotify on the mac and I have a iOS app (c-programming). Can I send data from the iOS app to my script that receives this data and make an action? I am trying a lot of things but nothing seems to work. Give me some ideas please...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way using `Remote Apple Events` because iOS has no AppleScript runtime engine.

What you can do is to create an application on both iOS and OS X (could be faceless on the Mac) to communicate with each other over the network via Bonjour. It's quite easy to implement a custom Bonjour Service